# How to visualize a NetCDF Dataset

Tags: python, netcdf, visualisation, python-3, xarray

Suppose I have a rather large `NetCDF` file that I open as a dataset using `xarray`.

```
import xarray

nc_in = r"....\D_P_WGS84_comp.nc"
nc_ds = xarray.open_dataset(nc_in)
```

It is composed of multiple raster variables, each with a single band, x, y coordinates and a crs (4326):

```
nc_ds
```

[image]

Suppose I want to visualize this very simply in my Python Notebook. I don't really want to add basemaps or legends or anything like that. I tried simply running `show(nc_ds) but throws an errors` AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'shape'`. I also noticed that the dimensions are frozen. What is the simplest way to visualize this dataset or a single variable of it in Python? Is there a mod or package extension that would do this?

Comment: Pretty sure you will need to select a DataArray from the DataSet, does `show(nc_ds.data_vars['F02_NBR_E0002'])` work?

Comment: It does! Thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for making me learn xarray today 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `Dataset` can contain more than one variable, it would not be trivial for software to know what you want it to display. If you select one of its variables as `DataArray` however, that can easily be displayed (if it is in an appropriate format).

The variables of a `Dataset` are available via its `data_vars` attribute. This exposes the variables as `DataArray`s in a dict with the variable names as keys.

Step by step:

```
variables = nc_ds.data_vars
f02_nbr_e0002 = variables['F02_NBR_E0002']
show(f02_nbr_e0002)
```

Efficient oneliner:

```
show(nc_ds.data_vars['F02_NBR_E0002'])
```

Comment: Thanks. I am somewhat new to working with xarray and rasters in this way and accessing the array in the data set to visualize it didn't occur to me (although originally, I had used `.open_rasterio` to turn the original tifs into a data array and visualize them). The 1-liner is great!